# Null Reference when Passing Parameter with Navigating Pages [WP8.1]

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, nullreferenceexception, windows-phone-8.1

I don't understand why or what I'm doing wrong, but I get a null reference exception when the follow code is executed in my Windows Phone 8.1 application:

First, the application navigates and passes the selectedStation to the next page...

Code from the MainPage:

```
    // When an item is selected, go to the next page and pass info
    private void listBoxStations_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the selected station item
        CompleteStation selectedStation = (CompleteStation)this.listBoxStations.SelectedItem;

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(StationInformationPage), selectedStation);


        // Make sure we set the selected index to -1 after item is selected so
        // when we come back to page, no items are selected
        this.listBoxStations.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Here is the code that is getting the null error in the next page:

```
    private CompleteStation station;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.station = (CompleteStation)e.Parameter;
        AddInformation();
    }

    private void AddInformation()
    {
        this.txtStationTitle.Text = station.StationName;
        // Add more information here
    }
```

The error is specifically happening when I try to change the txtStationTile.Text to station.StationName.

If I take out the code that changes the textbox, and I step through the program, it shows that the station variable is not actually null by the end of the OnNavigatedTo method...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not the station that's null, but the `this.txtStationTitle`.

You're doing everything in `OnNavigatedTo` while the page (XAML) including the TextBlock you're trying to change is not completely loaded, so the TextBlock is null and when you try to do `this.txtStationTitle.Text`, you get a NullReferenceException.

However, if you called `AddInformation` in `Loaded` event handler of the Page, then you'd be sure that the page is fully loaded and TextBlock would not be null anymore.

```
public SomePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += SomePage_Loaded;
}

void SomePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddInformation();
}
```

This type of exception is usually very easy to debug. Putting a breakpoint on the following line:

```
this.txtStationTitle.Text = station.StationName;
```

and examining `this.txtStationTitle` and `station` would make it really simple to find out what exactly is null.